# Binding textbox text to images canvas.leftProperty

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

How can I bind the text of a textbox to the value of an image's Canvas.GetLeft() Property in code and XAML?

textBox1
canvas1
image1

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="100" Text="{Binding ElementName=image1, Path=Canvas.LeftProperty}"></TextBox>
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx), you need parentheses, also you use the proper DP name, not the field:

```
Path=(Canvas.Left)
```

(Read up on syntax details like this [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx))